# boost_date_time_vc110-mt-1_49.dll is missing from your computer error

Tags: c++, matlab, boost, dll

I just installed ***Matlab 2016b*** and when I try to open it, this error prompts and the program doesn't start:

> boost_date_time_vc110-mt-1_49.dll is missing from your computer. try
>   reinstalling the program to fix this problem

I have ***visual studio 2015*** installed and I have compiled ***boost_1_62_0***. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You'll need to install the older boost version. Apparently your matlab version was linked against that one.

Comment: Thank you. But how should I install **boost 1.49** to get the exact library? I downloaded boost_1_49_0 and compiled it like this: bootstrap.bat
bjam toolset=msvc-10.0 --build-type=complete stage variant=debug,release threading=multi link=static .      Is it right?

Comment: Does it produce the DLL's you need?

Comment: no. it produces ddl files like this:          **boost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_62.dll**.

Comment: no. it produces dll files like this:          **boost_date_time-vc110-mt-1_62.dll**.